# (Pinescript) Permanently store current bar indicator state in a variable?

Tags: variables, conditional-statements

On tradingview pinesceript, is there a way to store the state of any indicator for the ongoing current bar inside a variable with a condition. ie, let's say that a filter is crossing the zero line and returning back under the zero line on the current bar. So is there a way to store in a variable the fact that a crossing has happened ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this has recently been made possible by the introduction of the [varip](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#op_varip) keyword, which enables variables declared with `varip` to retain their values between the updates of a real-time bar.